# How to get all controlled programs or tokens by an specified account?

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli

Can I see by API or something else all the programs or tokens when an specified account has authority to mint or update?

Answer (score 2):

To get all programs for which an address has deployed on the CLI, you could use

```
solana program show --programs
```

To list the tokens with which a user has authority over on the CLI, you could use the [spl-token CLI](https://spl.solana.com/token)

```
spl-token accounts
```

This will read the values of your local wallet.